# UK masters loan for EU-citizens after Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, study

As a EU-citizen, can I apply for a student loan for a master's degree in the UK for a course starting in September 2021, without moving to the UK before December 31?

Comment: From https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/eu-students, you’ll need settled or pre-settled status to get student finance if you’re starting a course on or after 1 August 2021. AFAIK, to get either, you must have started living in the UK by 31 December 2020 https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/what-settled-and-presettled-status-means